# Control template slider with different colors before / after a thumb

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to create a custom slider, that has different colors before and after a thumb - and I've managed to achieve that. The problem is, this is how it looks like: [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbUg1.png).

What I would like to achieve, is for a grey border to hide below a thumb - in the middle. However, when I try to set a negative margin in a DecreaseSliderButtonStyle border's, it overlaps a thumb.

There is a code: http://pastebin.com/5pcqHmDX (I think XAML formatting looks better on pastebin)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these styles:

```
<Style x:Key="DecreaseSliderButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border Height="18" Background="DimGray" CornerRadius="0,6,6,0" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>




<Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Grid>
                    <Border CornerRadius="9,0,0,9"
                            Background="DimGray"/>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="Black"
                             StrokeThickness="1"
                             Name="Ellipse"
                             Fill="Orange"></Ellipse>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you see a seam line between the thumb and the gray area, add this setter to the style of slider:

```
<Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
```

You might need to deal with corner radius of the border in the thumb to round it when value is very close to `Maximum`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I needed. Indeed, I have to deal with this mentioned corner radius, but I think I'll manage now.